# show multiple days in basic day view in Full Calendar

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, fullcalendar

Im using full calendar for my new project to show month,week & day events. Here on day button click, i want to show every day of the current month in basicDay view. For example from April 1 to April 30 with events one by one.

Here is my code

```
var date = new Date();
var d = date.getDate();
var m = date.getMonth();
var y = date.getFullYear();

var events_array = [
    {
    title: 'Test1',
    start: new Date(2012, 10, 1),
    allDay: false},
{
    title: 'Test2',
    start: new Date(2012, 10, 2),
    allDay: true}
];

$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,basicDay'
    },
    defaultView: 'month',
    events: events_array,       
}).on('click', '.fc-basicDay-button', function() { // code goes here });
```

if any alternative solution is there then please suggest.

My output should be like this

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4nWRJm-JCahVktDaFhXc0c0LUk/view?usp=sharing

The yellow color should be there only for current Date.

please help, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not possible with the available views by default. You need to create a [Custom View](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/views/Custom_Views/):

Something like:

```
views: {
        agendaTheWholeMonth: {
            type: 'agenda',
            duration: { days: 30 }
        }
    }
```

Or you can work in a totally custom new view. You have more details in the link above.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I got what i expect by creating a new view called agendaList. This view present in old FullCalendar of version 1.6.3.

This [link](http://paulthedutchman.nl/calendar_standalone/) will help you to get what you wanted.

Comment: Thanks for sharing! But I don't see any creation of new view. Just using agendaList view. Anyway, could you share your code here? So when you move your files, SO still maintain here the solution.

Comment: @MarioLevrero Actually the FullCalendar 1.6.3 doesn't have a view called agendaList. I created using custom views. This version of fullcalendar only supports few things and easy to understand the flow of plugin to alter the code.