# How to set time interval "day" instead of "hour" in full calendar timeline week view?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fullcalendar

I'm using Full Calendar timeline view and I need to show days in timelineWeek mode instead of hours. Can I create a custom view like that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29384023/show-multiple-days-in-basic-day-view-in-full-calendar

Comment: timeline view hasn't been released yet...

Comment: Has there been any answer?